# Difficulties with a string comparision function after a string reversal

Tags: c++, string

Below is a palindrome function and a helper function that implements a reverse operation. For some reason, even though the types appear to be the same, the if comparision statement never evaluates to true. Both variables s and comp seem to be strings, and I even tried calling stoi() on both to turn them into ints but comp for some reason throws an error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
Aborted (core dumped)

I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
bool palindrome (int n)
{

    string s = to_string(n);
    cout << s << endl;
    string comp = rev(s);
    cout << comp << endl;

    if (s == comp)
    {
        cout << s << " " << comp << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}

string rev (string &s)
{

    string return_string("");

    for (string::iterator it = s.end(); it != (s.begin() - 1); it--)
    {
        return_string += *it;
    }

    return return_string;

}
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @LogicStuff : It works perfectly though, copying a reversed string into a new one.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at [`std::string::rbegin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/)

Comment: [FYI] [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Answer (score 3):

Your `rev` function has two errors.  First, it computes `(s.begin() - 1)`.  Second, on its first iteration it dereferences `s.end()`.  Both are undefined behavior.

You'll have fewer problems using reverse iterators:

```
string rev( const string& s )
{
    string return_string;
    for ( auto it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); ++it )
    {
        return_string += *it;
    }

    return return_string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`for (string::iterator it = s.end(); it != (s.begin() - 1); it--)` is certainly wrong. In the first iteration, you'll be dereferencing `s.end()`, and then one before `s.begin()` . This is undefined behavior (even `s.begin() - 1` is).

Use reverse iterators:

```
for(auto it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); ++it)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (string::iterator it = s.end(); it != (s.begin() - 1); it--)
{
    return_string += *it;
}
```

end() points one beyond the end of the container, so when you dereference it you are accessing memory you don't own.
Also, trying to access more memory you don't own by decrementing begin() to an address before the start of your container.

Try using a reverse iterator, reverse end and reverse begin, like so:

```
string rev(const string &s)
{
    string return_string("");
    for (string::const_reverse_iterator rit = s.rbegin(); rit != s.rend(); ++rit)
    {
        return_string += *rit;
    }

    return (return_string);
}
```